# Use dplyr conditional filter in reactive function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, reactive, magrittr

I'm using dplyr in a Shiny app reactive function. I have an interactive widget in the UI that users can use to select status and data will be shown based on selected status. However I also want to give the option to show everything, which is a status that I have called 'All'.

I know how to achieve this without dplyr:

```
library(tibble)
library(shiny)

# Test Data -----
test_data <- tribble(
  ~id, ~status,
  1, 'active',
  2, 'inactive',
  3, 'test'
)

# Ui ----
ui = fluidPage(
  selectInput("status", "Choose a status:",
              choices = list("All","active","inactive","test")
  ),
  tableOutput('result')
)

# Server ----
server = function(input, output) {

  table <- reactive({
    if(input$status != 'All')
    {
      test_data <- test_data[test_data$status == input$status,]
    } else {
      test_data
    }
  })

  output$result <- renderTable(table(), rownames = FALSE)

}

# App ---
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**However**, I would like to be consistent with the rest of my code and use dplyr. Is there a way to do something like the below?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

# Test Data -----
test_data <- tribble(
  ~id, ~status,
  1, 'active',
  2, 'inactive',
  3, 'test'
)

# Ui ----
ui = fluidPage(
  selectInput("status", "Choose a status:",
              choices = list("All","active","inactive","test")
  ),
  tableOutput('result')
)

# Server ----
server = function(input, output) {

  table <- reactive({
    test_data %>%
      filter(ifelse(input$status != 'All', status == input$status, status == ***pass***))
  })

  output$result <- renderTable(table(), rownames = FALSE)

}

# App ---
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In other words, is there a way to use ifelse inside filter function to not filtering under a certain condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. You could do as follows:

```
if(input$status!="All")
  test_data %>% filter(status %in% input$status)
else
  test_data
```

So you only filter if the input is not "All". If you have a very long dplyr chain and you do not want to break it into pieces, you could also do:

```
if(input$status=="All")
  my_filter=unique(test_data$status)
else
  my_filter = input$status

test_data %>%
  filter(status %in% my_filter) %>%
  ..... %>%
  .....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The first example you posted needed an else otherwise it was print an empty table with option 'All' - I have edited your post to reflect that.
I like the second example you posted.

Comment: @Florian Why, maybe I'm missing something but the way I see it is that the only challenge is for dplyr's filter function to evaluate to `TRUE` depending `input$status == "All"` and return all rows.

Answer (score 7):

If your desire is to conditionally apply filter depending on the external value, you could attempt to use syntax:

## `TRUE`

```
table <- reactive({
  test_data %>%
    filter(if(input$status != 'All')  (status == input$status) else TRUE)
})
```

Passing `TRUE` as condition would then not filter any rows.

## `{}`

Alternative approach uses `{}` and returns untouched data set: **`else .`**.

```
table <- reactive({
  test_data %>%
  {if(input$status != 'All') filter(status == input$status) else .}
})
```

## `%<>%`

Finally you could consider breaking the pipe and using `%<>%` operator available in [`magrittr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package:

```
if(input$status != 'All') test_data %<>% filter(status == input$status)
```

Comment: Hi @Konrad, nice solution! I was unaware of the fact that you filter all rows by passing a a single `TRUE` in the `filter` statement.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
table <- reactive({
test_data %>%
filter(status == input$status | input$status == 'All')
})
```